# Django Rest Framework AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_default_basename'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my first time using viewsets and routers. When I run the server, it shows the that error.

Here is the view (inside a file called api.py):

```
class LeadViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Lead.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = LeadSerializer
```

serializer:

```
class LeadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import LeadViewset

router = routers.DefaultRouter
router.register('api/leads', LeadViewset, 'leads')
```

What am I doing wrong?
    urlpatterns = router.urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter
router.register('api/leads', LeadViewset, 'leads')
```

To:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/leads', LeadViewset, basename='leads')
```

Comment: it is showing this error now: `register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'viewset'`

Comment: I updated my code, please check. use -> () after DefaultRouter

Answer (score 0):

Modify your urls.py like this

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .api import LeadViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/lead',LeadViewSet,'lead')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Comment: I hope this would help someone and save you time